# Joomla 4.1.5 <meta name="keyword"> doesn't show

Tags: templates, joomla-4.x, header, jdocument

I use Joomla 4.1.5, and I created my own Joomla Template following the tutorial from joomla.org. My problem is that while other metadata shows correctly on the frontend pages, the `<meta name="keywords">` doesn't show, the other metadata is:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="dhany saguntoro">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="description" content="biaya bekam menurut rasulullah SAW">
    <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management">
```

I might have overlooked something within my Template Codes, but I don't know the missed things.

I want the  `<meta name="keywords">` shows in frontend pages, the shown  `<meta name="keywords">` must be data written in its own article data.

Comment: Meta keywords aren't necessarily worth the effort now-a-days - reading some of the forums info around SEO etc  (eg https://ahrefs.com/blog/meta-keywords/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created your own template...
The following code is working when posted inside `index.php`:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$app = Factory::getApplication();    
$document = $app->getDocument();
$name = 'keywords';
$value = 'school';
$document->setMetadata(htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

Isn't it?
And please, update Joomla to the latest 4.2.4

EDIT: There is no option to insert the `keywords` meta tag within Joomla 4 backend since this tag is considered irrelevant for SEO as explained in the comment under your question.